# who open link from adapter in retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, adapter

in my application need to open link by click
for retrofit i set adapter
and in my adapter my code :

```
holder.dlbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(queryVersiones.getDl_link());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

now i give error for startActivity ! i need help for fix this. tanks

Comment: I cannot understand Where's problem with this code? Where's the adapter object ?, and the retrofit callback method?, please edit your question to include the missed code or the problem from logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for fix this just need to add Context in your main class

```
Context mContext;
```

after this add context befor startActivity :

```
holder.dlbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(queryVersiones.getDl_link());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```